# Changing the anchorpoint and then rotating using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, rotation, translate-animation

I'm trying to rotate a UIView around a different anchor point. When I first create the UIView I set the anchor point to (0.0, 0.5). I rotate the view using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. When I click on the other side of the UIView, I want to set the anchor point to (1.0, 0.5). This moves the UIView to set the anchor point to the center point. I read on other answers that I should do this:
"multiply the bounds' width and height by the old and new anchorPoint's normalized values, take the difference of the two anchorPoints, and apply that difference to the position of the layer"

I tried that but I'm not able to set the UIView to the exact same position. Using this code:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, self.bounds.size.width, 0);
```

Set it to the exact same position but. When I rotate again (it should rotate around the new anchor point) it flips the UIView or something strange happens.

Answer (score 1):

When you re-locate the view due to the change in the anchor point, try not using the `transform` property. Instead, move your view using the `frame` property or the `center` property (or `position` if you are working with a CALayer object). Also, can you post more code showing how exactly rotate the view?

Comment: I rotate using
        theAngle = atan2(pointofTouch.y - self.center.y, pointofTouch.x - self.center.x);
        totalRadians = theAngle;
 self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);

I never got to re-locate the view to the exact same position using the frame or center.

Also, I have managed to fix part of the issue by using 
self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, totalRadians - oldRadians);
After translating. but this doesn't update the center, and so I rotate the view around the correct anchor point but from a different center (the center is never updated).

Comment: I know how you used translation because you clearly explained that point in the original posting. I was just saying moving frame could be a better practice sometimes (when you only do translations) because non-identity transformation makes frame property not available (but it's irrelevant to this case admittedly). Well, just glad you have fixed the issue. Next time provide more information (there's no way to fix totalRadians-oldRadians from your original question) about the situation and you will solve the problem even faster =)